# Changing a parent class to a child class depending on constructor parameters

Tags: php, class, oop, object, inheritance

I have a database class where you pass a table name into the constructor, kind of like this:

```
$customer =  new Dao("customer");
```

There are also specialized child classes for a few tables that have special behavior, like such:

```
class customerDao extends Dao{}
```

The reason for this is if someone is inserting a customer, there is certain logic that I want done every single time beforehand.

My goal is to allow the `Dao` class to be used for most tables but force the programmer to use one of these children classes if the table matches them. I want to make sure that if someone creates an object of the `Dao` class and passes in a table name that corresponds to one of these children classes, that it will instantiate the child class instead so that it's impossible to insert a customer without also running this logic code beforehand. Is there a way to do this?

If I have to, I can just have an array of prohibited table names and check for a match in the constructor, but I was hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: I'd change the way you're instancing this classes. I'd create some kind of wrapper/factory that decide what class to instantiate depending on the parameter. This factory can check if this custom class exists and return and instance. Unfortunately "forcing" programmers it's not the best way to arrive to elegant solutions.

Comment: Just wondering if my answer was helpful or not?

Comment: @miken32 Yes, it was. I was just waiting to see if there were any other answers or approaches before marking it as the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nothing can get returned from `__construct()` I think the only way you could get this to work would be using a static method to do your creation instead of `new`. You can dynamically check for the existence of the class, to prevent having to keep a list of such classes and their table name.

```
class Dao {
    public $table;
    public function __construct($table) { $this->table = $table; }
    public function whatami() { echo get_class($this) . "\n"; }
    public function gettable() { echo "$this->table\n"; }
    public static function create($table) {
        $cn = "${table}Dao";
        return class_exists($cn) ? new $cn() : new Dao($table);
    }
}

class customerDao extends Dao {
    public function __construct() { $this->table = "customer"; }
}

$foo = Dao::create("foo");
$foo->whatami();
$foo->gettable();
$bar = Dao::create("customer");
$bar->whatami();
$bar->gettable();
```

Output:

```
Dao
foo
customerDao
customer
```